# Get distinct values from columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following kind of data in my csv file

```
DriveNo   Date and Time           Longitude
156       2014-01-31 23:00:00     41.88367183
187       2014-01-31 23:00:01     41.92854
```

These data have a lot of noise. Sometimes, a driver(the DriveNo is unique) is present in two different locations at the same time , which is not possible and a noise. I tried to do it using distinct(select(five,DriveNo,Date and Time))

but i get the following error

> Error: unexpected symbol in "distinct(select(five,DriveNo,Date and"

However, when i try

```
distinct(select(five,DriveNo,Longitude))
```

it works.But, i need it with `DriveNo` and `Date and Time`.

Comment: You elected the problem for yourself by using a columnname with spaces ... Because of that you now have more to type: \`Date and Time\`

Comment: distinct(select(five,DriveNo,'Date and Time')) gives the following error: Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  "Date and Time"

Comment: Use backticks if you want to have spaces in your column names. But in general...don't

Comment: As other suggested, it is better to have column names without spaces, try with i.e. `df1 %>% setNames(., make.names(names(.))) %>% distinct(DriveNo, Date.and.Time)`

Comment: bacticks solve the problem. However , i lose my longitude column.Is there a way i retain the corresponding values in Longitude?

Comment: @SiddharthaBaral Look at my comment: there are the backticks. You used "..." and that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can escape with backticks, like:

```
df %>%
  select(DriveNo, `Date and Time`, Longitude) %>%
  distinct()
```

or using `group_by`, like:

```
   df %>%
      group_by(DriveNo, `Date and Time`) %>%
      select(Longitude) %>%
      unique()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.

Comment: @SiddharthaBaral glad. you may check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: The above code will give me the distinct DriverNo and Date and Time. However , i lose my longitude column.Is there a way i retain the corresponding values in Longitude?

Comment: use `group_by` instead of `select`, and then use `select` to keep all the columns you want? It'd be easier to help you with a better example.

Comment: I am very new to R and couldn't apply 'group_by'. I understand that it's the correct way to do it but am unable to correctly code it. Would to be able to help me? My ideal df would be same as the original df with no same DriveNo and Data and Time. There would still be Longitude.

Comment: It's not clear from your example why you need `distinct`. All entries in your example are distinct already. However, have modified the answer, this may help you.